# Difference between self.var and simply var

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, instance-variables, declared-property

What is the difference between using `self.var` vs. just `var` in an Objective-C class? Are there benefits or dangers to one or the other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between using obj-c accessors and using dot syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258360/whats-the-difference-between-using-obj-c-accessors-and-using-dot-syntax)  (Not an exact duplicate, but it's been brought up many times before)

Comment: I apologize about that. I would delete my question but the answers below are quite good.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed I don't have the option to delete it anymore. Sorry dor the duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foo = self.var;
self.var = foo;
```

is conceptually identical to

```
foo = [self var];
[self setVar: foo];
```

So using dot notation, you are really sending messages to self.

```
foo = var;
var = foo;
```

is conceptually the same as

```
foo = self->var;
self->var = foo;
```

So not using dot notation to access an instance variable is the same as treating self as a pointer to a C struct and accessing the struct fields directly.

In almost all cases, it is preferable to use the property (either dot notation or message sending notation).  This is because the property can be made to automatically do the necessary retain/copy/release to stop memory leaks.  Also, you can use [key value observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Concepts/Overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001837-BAJEAIEE) with a property.  Also subclasses can override properties to provide their own implementation.

The two exceptions to using properties are when setting an ivar in init and when releasing it in dealloc.  This is because you almost certainly want to avoid accidentally using a sub class override in those methods and you don't want to trigger any KVO notifications.

Answer (score 6):

`self.var` calls the *property* for `var`. Behind the scenes, Objective-C automatically generates a getter for properties (or you can make one yourself, if so inclined), so `self.var` uses that getter. Plain `var` accesses the instance variable directly (i.e., it doesn't go through the getter to get the value).

Comment: What is the benefit of going through the generated getter?

Comment: @MyNameIsEarl: Your getter could conceivably modify the ivar in some way (or even provide an ivar for a property that doesn't exist, if you wrote your own getter). Going through the getter also fires off KVO notifications, whereas direct access of the ivar doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of

- [How does dot syntax work without explicit @property in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844428/cocoa-dot-syntax-without-variable)
- [self.variable and variable difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536388/iphone-different-between-self-and-normal-variable)
- [What's the difference between using obj-c accessors and using dot syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258360/whats-the-difference-between-using-obj-c-accessors-and-using-dot-syntax)
- [iVars, With and Without self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318499/ivars-with-and-without-self)
- [Is "self" necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788903/is-self-necessary)

and probably about a dozen others that you could've found in about 15 seconds by using the "Search" box up in the top right corner of the site.