# Use (or not) of self. in Objective-C properties

Tags: objective-c, syntax, self

I've got a doubt about assigning values to properties in Objective-C. I've had a lot of problems of "misteriously missed" values, for example if I have this interface:

```
// MyClass.h
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    MyOtherClass *myVar;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MyOtherClass *myVar;

- (id)initWithValue:(NSString *)val;
```

And this implementation:

```
// MyClass.m
@implementation MyClass

@synthesize myVar;

- (id)initWithValue:(NSString *)val {
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil) {
        /** Do some stuff with val... **/
        myVar = [method:val]; // Some method that returns a MyOtherClass value
    }

    return self;
}
```

At some point of the execution, the value of myVar disappears, changes or something else... And the solution is to change:

myVar = [method:val]; // Some method that returns a MyOtherClass value

for

**self**.myVar = [method:val]; // Some method that returns a MyOtherClass value

So... what is the diference between using self or not using it? I mean, it's clear that I've to use it because if not it will cause problems but I don't know why

Thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between calling self.var vs var](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627646/difference-between-calling-self-var-vs-var)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example of why you should change your `@synthesize` to `@synthesize myVar = _myVar;` or some variation of that. Without doing that, it is possible to set your instance variable out from under you as a direct assignment of `myVar = nil" would bypass your setter.

Using the `myVar = _myVar` strategy will cause the compiler to complain if you attempt to do `myVar =` and will require you to call `self.myVar` which will access your setter or getter.

The only place you should then use `_myVar` is if you change the declaration of your setter or getter for that variable.

Comment: Good, but I do not agree on the last part. There are situations in which it may be more appropriate to use the variable directly. Those being situations where you a) need to worry about performance, since calling the getter/setter is another method call or b) alloc/init an object and want to save the release

Comment: True, but you are only going to notice a performance issue if you are calling your setter or getter repeatedly (many, many, many times) very tight loop.

Answer (score 3):

If you use self, you're using the property and it is marked with "retain".  If you use the variable, you're bypassing the property, therefore no "retain".  You could write `myVar = [[someObject method:val] retain];` and get the same effect as the property.

Answer (score 0):

What method are you calling on `val`?

I would imagine that when you do

```
myVar = [method:val]; // Some method that returns a MyOtherClass value
```

The result is an autoreleased object. That means that when your init method finishes your `myVar` object is released and gets destroyed. The `myVar` variable still points to the place in memory where the object was, but that memory could get filled with anything.

When you use the property setter method using the dot syntax like this

```
self.myVar = [method:val];
```

The setter method that is automatically synthesised for you by the compiler will send the object a retain message to keep it around.

You could also fix your code error like this:

```
myVar = [[method:val] retain]; // Some method that returns a MyOtherClass value
```

but its better to stick to the dot syntax.

Comment: These days, it's best to just assume ARC, in which case this isn't an issue.

Comment: They're not using ARC, as under ARC you can't use the `retain` keyword for a property . If they were using ARC the equivalent keyword would be `strong`

Comment: I agree that the submitter would probably benefit from ARC though

Comment: Incorrect; `retain` is still valid as a property qualifier under ARC. You generally would use `strong` instead of `retain`, but since it appears in a header, and since ARC sources can interact with non-ARC classes (and #import non-ARC headers), `retain` and `strong` are synonymous in property declarations.

Comment: But reading the question again, it does appear that he may be non-ARC, since he says the value is disappearing on him.

Comment: well it appears you're right and you can use retain instead of strong. I had assumed as the convert to ARC process changes the keywords. :) Answer in general seems correct though

Comment: As @BJHomer says I'm not using ARC (so effectively the value disappears). Thank you every one for your help